# cover-video background does not work properly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design, html5-video

I am trying to attach a video as a background to an article section. The issue is that in small screens it is displayed only in the 1/3 of the article. To implement that I used the article class, a background div as a wrapper and the video element id. Any ideas?

```
<article class=”myArticle”>

 <div class="fullscreen-bag">

       <video id="videoBack">
          <source src=" " type="video/mp4">
          <source src=" " type="video/ogg">
          <source src=" " type="video/webm">
       </video>

 </div> 

 <div class="container">
      //
      //
 </div> 


</article>

//Css

.myArticle {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.fullscreen-bag {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#VideoBack {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -100;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution. I deleted the #VideoBack rules, and i applied the .fullscreen-bag inside the video tag.